# How can I load a kmap into my buildroot init?

Tags: c, linux, init, buildroot, busybox

So I've just downloaded my kmap with this command:

> sudo busybox dumpkmap > qwerty.kmap

Now I need to load it into my buildroot image, I thought about adding it into the init file, but I don't really know how to achieve this, thanks.